# Flutter avoid multiple bloc creation

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-routes

I use `MaterialApp.router`.
the build function of MainRouterDelegate is called 4 times.
Every time it's called, a screen and its bloc are created.
In the bloc, I make HTTP calls. I don't want to make the same calls every time the bloc is created.
How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

1. If there is only one instance of the bloc in the whole app, you can add a BlocProvoder above MaterialApp and the bloc will be available anywhere in the app, for any route.
2. If there are blocs for specific elements identified by some unique id that you need to create on the fly, but you want to make sure you only create once, you can use essentially a main bloc or just getIt to keep track of a map of IDs to blocs that have already been instantiated. When you need to provide a bloc in a build function that might be called repeatedly, just check first if you already have a copy of the bloc you are trying to provide in your bloc-map. If not, create one and save it with the element's ID.

Comment: I'd like to do something like [1] but I want to pass the bloc some parameters from the url, so I only have them in MainRouterDelegate's build function (which is called multiple times).

Comment: You can add those parameters to the bloc as an event also as you get them, and just listen for when the bloc is fully initialized

Comment: So you mean to add them to the bloc one I have them (by a listener in the bloc or just calling a function in the bloc, because I can access it with the provider, right?) and if the bloc is already set, just ignore the next calls?

Comment: Say in initState of the page that is controlled by your bloc, if you can retrieve the id info your bloc needs, you can just add an event to your bloc with that info, like "bloc.add(InitializeBloc(param));" and in your bloc, when you get the InitializeBloc event, do whatever processing or retrieving you need to do and then yield a state with, for example, status = "initialized'; so the bloc builder would just wait for the initialized state before showing the page.